# Vertical ListView / CoverFlow centering the selected image

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, gallery, center

i have searched and tried a lot in this topic. What i'm trying to do is basically a vertical Gallery/CoverFlow. I am aware that this should be done with a custom ListView. And i have done exactly that.

When doing this i appear to have 2 problems i just can't solve:

i) When scrolling in the List i want the items to move in "slots". Most importantly the centered item should move exactly above a roundRect i drew. For better visualization: That's exactly what the "CoverFlow" does, but in a horizontal way. Trying to override onScrollStateChanged seem to work non-determinstically. This is the way i tried that:

```
       public void registerScrollListener(){
       setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if(scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
            int first = getFirstVisiblePosition();
            int last = getLastVisiblePosition();

            List<View> childs = new ArrayList<View>();

            for(int i = first; i < last; i++){
                childs.add(getChildAt(i));
            }
            int centerHeight = getHeightCenterOfSideView();
            int centerPos = 0;
            int distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for(View childView : childs){
                int newDist = Math.abs(centerHeight - (childView.getTop() + (childView.getHeight()/2)));
                if(newDist < distance){
                    distance = newDist;
                    centerPos = childs.indexOf(childView);
                }
            }
            View childView = getChildAt(centerPos);
            smoothScrollToPosition(centerPos, centerHeight - (childView.getTop() + (childView.getHeight()/2)));
        }
        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
   }
```

ii) When scrolling in a non-circular ListView, i can't center the last or first item as the listview is empty when scrolling further. A possibility to do this is to add some extra-items at the end and the top. Problem is that i would like to use the listview separators and it looks ugly with empty views in it. The other thing is that i want do make this undependant of the display size, which should be difficult, seeing that the last item will not be centered exactly.

Could anyone help me with any of these two questions? The easiest would be to just take some existing code.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, my solution was to take kankan's wheel-widget and modify it the way i need it. Some very usefull hints were in there.